# How to show count of number of characters entered in a contentEdible div?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-hooks

Based on the code in [this great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66328341/how-to-highlight-text-based-on-user-input-with-react), I have the following React app which will highlight user input text after N number of characters are entered. This uses an event change with the [innerText](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/innerText) of an HTML element, and puts the "extra characters" in a stylized span:

```
import React, { useRef} from "react";


export default function App() {

  // create a custon contentEditable div
  const EditDiv = (props) => {

    let textRef = useRef(null);  // grab innerHTML

    // on change event
    const contentChange = (event) => {

      let html = event.target.innerText; // inner text, no HTML tags

      // users add input, no problem
      // but once inner text length greater than the max length:
      if (html.length > props.charLimitLength) {

        // text before limit hit
        let start =  html.slice(0, props.charLimitLength);
        // text after limit hit
        let overlimit =  html.slice(props.charLimitLength);
        // style overlimit with span tag
        overlimit = `<span style="background:${props.highlightColor}">${overlimit}</span>`;
        //set text as innerHTML 
        textRef.current.innerHTML = start + overlimit
        
        // set the cursor at the end of innerHTML; otherwise, cursor jumps to start
        let range = document.createRange();
        let selection = window.getSelection();  // represents the range of text selected by the user 
        range.setStart(textRef.current.lastChild, 1);

        selection.removeAllRanges();
        selection.addRange(range);

      }
    }

    return <div>
         Characters: {countChar}
        <div ref={textRef} contentEditable onInput={contentChange}></div>
        </div>
  }
  
  return (
    <div>
      <b> Enter text in the div here, max length 10: </b>
      <EditDiv charLimitLength={10} highlightColor={"red"} />
    </div>
  )
}
```

My problem is that, I would like to show the count of the characters as well.

Normally, I would try this with the React hook `useState()`, e.g.

```
const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
```

but in this case, using `setCount(html.length)` i.e. `setCount(event.target.innerText.length)` isn't an option, as it's out of scope for showing the count, e.g. `<p> You typed {count} characters </p>`

I'm stumped how to do this.

In terms of my larger goals, I'm trying to recreate the Twitter character count feature here: [image]

After 280 characters, the text is highlighted:

[image]

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by _`setCount(event.target.innerText.length)` isn't an option, as it's out of scope for showing the count, e.g. `<p> You typed {count} characters </p>`_?

Comment: @ArunKumarMohan I should explain better. If you try it, the `setCount()` needs to be in `contentChange`. But It will then erase the innerHTML content.

Comment: Why would it erase the content? Not sure if I'm missing something. See if my answer helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a state variable to track the character count and update it in the `contentChange` function.

```js
const [count, setCount] = useState(0)

const contentChange = (event) => {
  const html = event.target.innerText
  setCount(html.length)

  if (html.length > props.charLimitLength) {
    setCount(props.charLimitLength - html.length)
    // rest of the code
  }
}
```

[Working CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/immutable-glitter-0jg4n?)

**Screenshots**

Positive character count when the text length is less than the max length (10)

[image: positive character count]

Negative character count when the text length exceeds the max length (10)

[image: negative character count]

Comment: Thanks! This is the part that didn't click for me `setCount(props.charLimitLength - html.length)`

Seems obvious now. I just wasn't using the hook correctly

Comment: No worries! Happy to help.